# Vertica rpm installation fails

Tags: linux, rpm, vertica

I am trying to upgrade a 3-node Vertica cluseter to the most recent version 7.2.3. I tried running the following command:

```
rpm -Uvh vertica-7.2.3-0.x86_64.RHEL6.rpm
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
Preparing...                ###########################################  [100%]
ERROR: AdminTools process still running.
ERROR: You must quit adminTools prior to upgrade.
dbadmin 1456 1455 0 14:22 ? 00:00:00 /opt/vertica/oss/python/bin/python     /opt/vertica/bin/adminTools -t command_host -cstart
error: %pre(vertica-7.2.3-0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping vertica-7.2.3-0
```

I am not running any AdminTools process. However, I am not sure if someone has a screen open that is running something. How do I force close the AdminTools process?

[Update 1]

Output of ps auxwww|grep -i admin

```
root       925  0.0  0.0 103244   892 pts/3    S+   21:01   0:00 grep -i admin
dbadmin   1440  0.0  0.0 106060  1368 ?        Ss   14:22   0:00 /bin/bash       /opt/vertica/agent/agent.sh /opt/vertica/config/users/dbadmin/agent.conf
dbadmin   1451  0.8  0.0 1381652 43228 ?       Sl   14:22   3:24 /opt/vertica/oss/python/bin/python ./simply_fast.py
root      1455  0.0  0.0 155712  1768 ?        S    14:22   0:00 su -l    dbadmin -c /opt/vertica/bin/adminTools -t command_host -cstart
dbadmin   1456  0.0  0.0 432844 21740 ?        Ss   14:22   0:00  /opt/vertica/oss/python/bin/python /opt/vertica/bin/adminTools -t command_host -cstart
dbadmin   1526  0.0  0.0  59820  3748 pts/1    Ss+  14:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=30 -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -l dbadmin 10.164.97.8
dbadmin   1527  0.0  0.0  59820  3748 pts/2    Ss+  14:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=30 -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -l dbadmin 10.164.97.9
dbadmin  30185  0.0  0.0 101428   596 ?        Ss   17:36   0:02 /opt/vertica/bin/rsync --daemon --config=/tmp/vbr_rsyncd/vbr_rsyncd.conf --port=50000
```

Comment: `ps auxwww|grep -i admin` and see what comes up.

Comment: Added the output...I see a few running as dbadmin...should I kill all of these manually?

Comment: no idea. the ssh ones are running the commands on remote machines and can probably be left alone. the others... kill at your own risk.

Comment: Killing the two adminTools processes did the trick...thanks

Comment: It gave you the `ps` output in the error - `kill -9 1456` should have done it.

Answer (score 0):

The error output includes the problematic PID:

> ERROR: You must quit adminTools prior to upgrade.
>   dbadmin 1456 1455 0 14:22 ? 00:00:00 /opt/vertica/oss/python/bin/python     /opt/vertica/bin/adminTools -t command_host -cstart

More generally, if the installation fails because some Vertica process is still running, grepping for "vertica" in your process list will generally find it.  By default Vertica installs into /opt/vertica.